# Что делает эта строка?

Tags: javascript, время

```
var lastLoopRun = 0;
if (new Date().getTime() - lastLoopRun > 40) {
    Какое-то действие;
}
```

Хотел бы узнать, что делает эта строка в условии if?
Заранее больше спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: Это условие в конструкции `if` - означает, что если время больше 40, значит, что-то делаем.

Comment: проверяет, является ли время в миллисекундах   от 1 января 1970 года  00:00:00  минус lastLoopRun  больше чем 40

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Новый экземпляр класса Date (читайте: new Date) указывает на текущую дату и время (установленное на компьютере пользователя). 
Метод getTime() позволяет получить количество миллисекунд, прошедших с 1 января 1970 года (это называется timestamp). 
Получается, что в вашем примере в условии if проверяется больше ли разница количества миллисекунд, прошедших с 1 января 1970 года, и значения переменной lastLoopRun, чем 40